# Form for Profile models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Is there a way to create a form from profile models ?

For example... If I have this model as profile:

```
class blogger(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    born = models.DateTimeField('born')    
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=gender )
    about = models.TextField(_('about'), null=True, blank=True)
```

.

I want this form:

Name:

Surname:

Born:

Gender:

About:

Is this possible ? If yes how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the extra fields to the ModelForm.

```
class BloggerForm(forms.ModelForm):
  name=forms.CharField()
  surname=forms.CharField()

  class Meta:
    model=blogger
    exclude=('user',)
```

You can then override the clean/save methods to deal with your new data

Answer (score 2):

Use [Modelforms](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Comment: ModelForms doesn't display name and surname ma only a user select.